# Unexplainable UI Presentation Problem

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, firebug

[image]

Can anyone explain the weird presentation behavior in the UI screenshot above?  As you can see, there's an undesirable separation between  the insurance type and the top of the row.  When looking at the code via Firebug, there's a clear break in the code.  You can view this oddity in the code screenshot below.

[image]

The div.insurance-type parent container has no CSS styles.  In other words, the vertical-align property, the margin-top property, the padding-top property, and the float property are set to default values and don't inherit a value that might cause this presentation.  The children divs have this style:

```
div#worklist table tr td.col-InsuranceType div.insurance-type div {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

The span.insurance-company has this style:

```
div#worklist table tr td.col-InsuranceType div.insurance-type span.insurance-company {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The components of this web app are:

- ASP.NET MVC 3
- Razor View Engine
- jQuery 1.5.1
- SQL Server 2008
- IIS 7.5

This issue occurs in FF4, IE8 and IE7.  Please let me know if you know the root cause of this unexplainable presentation behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: what about div.bold and span.insurance-company? Do they have styles attached?

Comment: I'm guessing ^that's it. If not, give us a link so we can have a look.

Comment: If you can't provide a live link, you need to make a test case that we can look at. Steps to do this: open the page in Firefox. View Source, copy it all. Paste into [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/). Redact any sensitive information. Add your CSS inside `<style></style>`. Remove anything irrelevant that you can, just make sure the test case has the same problem.

Comment: @DA and @Frits van Campen, I just added the styles in question.

@thirtydot, I can create a test, but will time to do it.

Comment: when you have a selector like this: `div#worklist table tr td.col-InsuranceType div.insurance-type div` there's likely a LOT going on in that CSS. That's pretty messy. Open your page up with FireBug and start deleting classes in the HTML until you find the one(s) that are causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess since I can't see the actual page, could there be some garbage character between the td and div that even firebug has trouble displaying? If the content is not client-side generated (ie: via Ajax), try viewing the source in Firefox (Ctrl-U or Cmd-U) and see if there is any weird character in there. I would even go as far as looking at the raw data in Fiddler.

On a different note, `<div class="bold">` is bad practice (not semantic), use `<strong>` instead. :)

Comment: while `<div class="bold">` may be bad practice, it is so because it's failing to separate presentation from content. `<strong>` indicates semantics that may or may not be appropriate for the content being marked up and should not be used blindly as a substitute for bold presentation.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
[Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

Comment: No dice.  The parent container has no styles, including vertical-align:middle, applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<div class="insurance-type">
   <div class="bold">
    <span class="insurance-company"
```

have you tried:

```
<div class="insurance-type"><div 
  class="bold"><span 
    class="insurance-company">
```

Comment: Tried removing all unnecessary white spaces with no luck.